# Free an assigned pointer

Tags: c, free

Does the following code free the memory that was allocated for `x`?

```
int main()
{
    char *x = (char*)calloc(100, sizeof(char));
    char *y = x;
    free(y);
}
```

Comment: yes, it does free the memory allocated for x

Comment: [Don't cast `malloc()` (or `calloc()`)!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3488231)

Comment: @AndreyChernukha , The answer to that is [it depends](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30000348/3049655). (You posted that comment *before* the OP's edit)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Yes**

When you do

```
char *y = x;
```

you make `y` point to the location where `x` points to. Since `y` points to a memory location returned by `calloc`,

```
free(y);
```

is perfectly valid. As [@haccks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2455888/haccks) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985497/free-an-assigned-pointer/29985670?noredirect=1#comment48099808_29985670), this would not work if you make `y` point to another memory location, provided that this memory location wasn't returned by `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`.

---

In C, you [should not cast the result of `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Also, checking the return value of `calloc` to see if it was successful is good. `calloc` will return `NULL` on failure.

Comment: It would be nice if you add that this not work if `y` is reassigned to another memory location.

Comment: Technically, `free(NULL)` is legal and a no-op, so in this extremely simplistic example, OP's code is perfectly fine not checking the return value.

Comment: @Kevin , I know. That's why I never said "you should".

Comment: So if I do ```y++``` before ```free(y)```, the memory space which x pointed to will not be freed, right?

Comment: @Alec.Zhou IIRC that will invoke undefined behavior. You should only `free` whatever  was returned by `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`

Answer (score 5):

The original version of the question had

```
int *y = x;
free(y);
```

I.e. assigning the `char` pointer to an `int` pointer and then invoke `free()` on the `int` pointer. The signature of `free()` is [`void free(void *ptr);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) so irrespective of `char *` vs. `int *`, memory would be released.

The edited (and current) version of the question has

```
char *y = x;
free(y);
```

Here, both `y` and `x` points to the same memory. This is known as *pointer aliasing*. Upon the call to `free()`, that memory would certainly be released.

A problem, however, is that after `free(y)`, the pointer `x` would be *dangling*, i.e. the memory it is pointing to is no longer valid.

Note, it is neither necessary nor recommended to cast the return value from `calloc`.

Comment: `char * x = ...; int * y = x;` provokes undefined behaviour, due to assigning to an incompatible pointer type. Afterwards anything can happen. So the correct answer would be "*May be.*".

Comment: Assigning "to an incompatible pointer type" does not - in itself - cause undefined behaviour.   Undefined behaviour results if that pointer of incompatible type is dereferenced.   The code in the original version of the question did not do that, so did not exhibit undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

The method is `void free(void *ptr)`, then when you make `char* y = x`, you have a pointer to the same space memory that `y` was pointing.

That let you free that space later with `free (y)`.

However, you would put `x = NULL` because now `x` doesn't have a own space despite it have a value.

For further information about free read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/free).

Answer (score 0):

The memory returned by your call of `calloc()` is released by the call of `free()`.

In your code that affects both `x` and `y`.