# Does freeing an int* which was assigned to a char* (allocated by `malloc`) invoke Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, free, undefined-behavior

The title maybe confusing. Suppose `str` is a pointer allocated by `malloc`. `ptr`, of type `int*`, is assigned to it and is freed as shown by the code snippet below:

```
char* str = malloc(64);
int* ptr = str;

free(ptr);
```

I've tried to compile the above code. It just gives a warning:

```
source_file.c: In function ‘main’:
source_file.c:10:16: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
     int* ptr = str;
                ^
```

Does the above code invoke Undefined Behavior?
Does the above code snippet free the memory allocated by `malloc` for `str`?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? The code above gives `error: cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘int*’ in initialization` with gcc 4.9.2.

Comment: I was thinking of posing this question also, after this one question yesterday. Thanks for following up on this ... :-)

Comment: @farukdgn , Got that error when compiling using g++ in C++. GCC seems to compile it. I'm using GCC 4.8.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does the above code invoke Undefined Behavior?

It depends.

From C11 draft 6.3.2.3/7:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
>   resulting pointer is not correctly aligned) for the referenced type, the behavior is
>   undefined.

As the alignment for a `char` might be different from an `int`, that is probably less restrictive, assigning a `char * pc` to an `int * pi` might lead to `pi` being misaligned.

However for the **specific** example given by the OP:

```
char * pc = malloc(64);
int * pi = pc;
```

the behaviour would be defined, as (See *[Alter Mann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1606345/alter-mann)*'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000240/does-freeing-a-pointer-which-was-assigned-to-another-pointer-of-another-type-al#comment48119661_30000348)) `malloc()` is guaranteed to return a block of memory properly aligned.

From C11 draft 7.22.3:

> The
>   pointer returned [by aligned_alloc, calloc, malloc, and realloc] if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to
>   a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement ...

An example which **would** lead to undefined behaviour, due to misalignment, is:

```
char * pc = malloc(64);
int * pi = pc + 1;
```

---

> Does the above code snippet free the memory allocated by malloc for str?

In case the former assignment would have introduced undefined behaviour this question is irrelevant, as anything could happen with UB having been invoked already.

If else the prior assignment wouldn't have invoked UB, the call to `free()` would perfectly de-allocate the block of memory referenced, as converting back the pointer value from `int *` to `void *`, as originally provided by `malloc()`, is well defined.

From C11 draft 6.3.2.3/7 (cont/):

> Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the
>   original pointer

and

From C11 draft 6.3.2.3/1:

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to
>   any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall
>   compare equal to the original pointer

Comment: But on the other hand: `The block that malloc gives you is guaranteed to be aligned so that it can hold any type of data.`

Comment: "*is guaranteed to be aligned*" is it?

Answer (score 4):

No. It doesn't invoke *undefined behaviour*. The warning is simply about incompatible types which you could cast.

```
char* str = malloc(64);
int* ptr = (int*) str;
free(ptr);
```

`free` does take a void pointer and the above has no problems. However, using the result of such a value *may* invoke undefined behaviour due to alignment of int type and char type. As such the conversion of `char*` to `int*` itself doesn't lead to undefined.

Comment: As per the Standard (see my answer) if the aligment of the target type is not given, just the assignment already invokes UB.

Comment: Not sure which part you referenced says assignment of char ptr to int ptr leads to UB. As I said in answer, only *using* it could lead UB.

Comment: I gave an example in my answer on when just the assigment would provoke UB. Your code as well as the OP's code does not provoke UB.

Comment: @BlueMoon: On a platform where an `int` store at an unaligned address would not trap, but would simply ignore the lower bits of the address (overwriting nearby data), having some kinds of compiler-generated validation of alignment would be helpful.  Having compilers trap attempts to cast or coerce an unaligned `char*` to `int*` would likely be much cheaper than would trapping all accesses made using pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the above code invoke Undefined Behavior?

No.

> Does the above code snippet free the memory allocated by malloc for str?

Yes.

Just for clarification, some notes on UB regarding dynamic allocation:

Memory returned by `malloc` is aligned to take any possible value. Such memory has no declared type and its effective type is set through storage.

If you do

```
*ptr = 42;
```

the first `sizeof (int)` bytes of the memory block will now be of type `int` and may only be read as such, ie

```
float val = *(float *)ptr;
```

will be UB.

However,

```
*(float *)ptr = 42.0;
```

would be legal as it re-sets the effective type, now in turn making reads through `*ptr` invalid.

In addition, it is always legal to access any object through pointers of type `char` or `unsigned char`.

Comment: I am sorry it turns out that when I was fiddling with my mobile 2 days ago, I accientally downvoted you. I can't undo it without an edit.

Comment: @BlueMoon: no worries; technically, your edit should read `char`, `signed char` or `unsigned char` - these are all different types, though 2 of them will have the same representation ;)

Comment: Right. I was mainly looking to make some simple edit rather than to correct anything :)

Answer (score 0):

It may invoke UB, based on endianness, alignments or such int vs char typecasting when accessed. When you do malloc all it does is return a `void*` which can be of any data type(and in some cases may require typecasting). It doesn't make a difference if you put a pointer in char* to int*, but there would be difference in access units, i.e in case of ints 4 bytes at a time vs in char 1 byte at a time. So, that code in your question wouldn't invoke UB, but memory accesses might.

As for second question, yes calling free on `ptr` will cause memory pointed by `str` also to be freed. Now, `str` would be a dangling pointer.

Comment: "*may require typecasting*" in C it will never.

Comment: In C++ you would need typecasting.

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language. This question is about C.