# Input returns the correct string but doesn't run the function

Tags: c, string, malloc, getline, strlen

I have the following code:

```
bool get_command(char *cmd){
    char *cm = (char*)malloc(strlen(cmd));
    strcpy(cm,cmd);
    const char *tok = strtok(cm," ");
if(!tok)
    return false;

if(!strcmp(tok,"MULTIPLY"))
{
    printf("WORKING!\n");
    return true
}
....




int main(void){
  while(1){
    char *input = NULL;
    char buf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};
    int read;
    size_t len;
    read = getline(&input, &len, stdin);
    if (-1 != read){
      printf("Input: %s\n", input);
      sprintf(buf, "%s", input);
      get_command(input);
    } else {
       printf("No line read\n");
   }
   free(input);
  }
 return 0;
}
```

When I run the code and input `MULTIPLY` it returns

> input: MULTIPLY
>
> TOKEN: MULTIPLY

However this doesn't print out the `WORKING`. Could anyone explain why this does not work as expected?

Comment: Try to print `tok` after `strtok` call.

Comment: @tivn tok is the same as input which should call the printf function but does not work

Comment: Is `tok` equal to `"MULTIPLY\n"` by any chance?

Comment: @D.Shawley it wasn't! I found out from the comment from Cool Guy!

Comment: before returning from get_command(), need to call 'free(cm)'  otherwise the code will have a memory leak

Comment: get_command() returns either true or false, however, main() is ignoring the returned value

Comment: regarding the call to malloc(): 1) in C, do not cast the returned value  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: I would also recommend replacing code that looks like `char *p = malloc(strlen(q) + 1); strcpy(p, q);` with `char *p = strdup(q);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you need to change

```
char *cm = (char*)malloc(strlen(cmd));
```

to

```
char *cm = malloc(strlen(cmd) + 1);
```

to have space for terminating null character.

The `strlen()` does not count the terminating null and if you don't allocate memory for holding the null during copying, you'll be facing memory overrun causing [undefined behavior.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) of `strcpy()`

> `char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);`
>
> The `strcpy()` function copies the string pointed to by `src`, including the terminating null byte (`'\0'`), to the buffer pointed to by `dest`. The strings may not overlap, and the destination string `dest` must be large enough to receive the copy.

That said, as per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) of `getline()`

> `getline()` reads an entire line from stream, storing the address of the buffer containing the text into `*lineptr`. The buffer is null-terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found.

As your delimiter string does not include the `\n`, the token will have the `\n` into it. To avoid, do either of following

- include `\n` in delimiter string
- use `strncmp()` for comparison.
- strip down the `\n` after taking the input.

Also, please [do no cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: Hmm I was thinking it was something with the null terminators so I tried this but it seems to not print anything still.

Comment: @KadanaKanz , Try adding `cmd[strcspn(cmd,"\n")]=0` at the start of `get_command`

Comment: @KadanaKanz `getline()` reads and stores the _newline_ to the input buffer. you can try `strncmp()` instead, it'll work. or you have to strip down the trailing `\n`.

Comment: @CoolGuy that worked! Thank you! (got some good reading on it too! :))

Comment: @Sourav thanks for the information I'll be sure to do that next time.

Comment: @KadanaKanz You're welcome. :-) updated my answer to address this issue.

Comment: Why did you remove the cast? g++ or gcc gives `error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]` without casting.

Comment: @farukdgn please see the last line of my answer for a link to the answer to your query. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh If you don't cast you can NOT compile it since gcc gives `error`, not `warning`. So, what should we do?

Comment: @farukdgn , [Again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000240/does-freeing-a-pointer-which-was-assigned-to-another-pointer-of-another-type-al#comment48120077_30000240), when I compile in C++, I get that error. It seems that you are compiling in C++ mode using GCC. In C++, the cast *is* required while in C, the cast should be removed.